# nhibernate many to many where look up is not the id field

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm going to simplify the problem I'm having.  So let's suppose we have an NHibernate domain of pets, with Spot the dog, Fluffy the cat, Hunter the cat, and SSSS the snake so in the db these guys would look like:

```
ID  Name     Species
1   Spot     1
2   Fluffy   2
3   Hunter   2
4   SSSS     3
```

And we have a species table

```
ID Species
1  Dog
2  Cat
3  Snake
```

And let's say we have a skin-type table with these two entries

```
ID  Type
1   Furry
2   Scaley
```

And a look up table that looks like

```
Species   Type
1         1
2         1
3         2
```

How do I map this so that will pull the type of skin in with the object.

I've looked at a mapping file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
namespace="menagerie"
assembly="menagerie">
<class name="Pet" table="Pets">
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="id" />
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <many to one name="Species"
          class="PetSpecies"
          column="Species"
          cascade="all" />
    <bag name="SkinType" table="Species_SkinType" cascade="none" lazy="false">
      <key column="Species" />
      <many-to-many class="SkinType" column="[type]" />
    </bag>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

However, the bag that's supposed to be filled with the pet's skin type wants to use the pet's id as the look up key value, not the pet's species.  How do I get it to use the pet's species to populate the skintype for the pet?

Answer (score 1):

I would map SkinType as a many-to-one relationship from Pet. The many-to-many table that links Species to SkinType should be used in the UI and validation to only allow valid SkinTypes to be selected for a Species. I would not try to enforce this constraint in the model.

Comment: How can you map skin type as a many to one from pet?  There's no field on Pet that gives skin type?

Comment: You have it mapped as a bag on Pet so I assumed that's where you wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the `foreign-key` attribute would help?  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085064/nhibernate-many-to-many-mapping/3161934#3161934)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out.

The bag shouldn't be on the Pet class but on the Species class.

So there is no Fluffy.Skintype = furry, instead there is Fluffy.Cat.Skintype = furry.

Comment: It seems obvious now that you say it :)